# Default HTTP header in web API responses

Tags: http, go, http-headers

Im attempting to set a default header in my Golang web api. I am using the net/http router that comes with Go. I can find many examples of how to do this :

- Using some other routers.
- Doing it for every response ( I am already doing it )

Is it there a way in which I can set a default header for all responses using net/http?

Comment: Wrap your router in a handler type that sets the header and then invokes the original router. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/JRFXsvUmFmP

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper function. Something like:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func SetDefaultHeaders(handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Set default headers
        handler(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", SetDefaultHeaders(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // ...
    }))
}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go. This is generically a wrapper function, but in the specific case of HTTP handlers this is commonly referred to as a middleware.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. It works flawlessly and its really clever. the only problem I have is that the routes I don't define, for instance, when I give an invalid path and get a 404, the response I get of course it does not have this.